# div operation wraps over (x86 assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have a procedure I'm calling in x86 assembly (MASM) in Visual studio 2010.
All it's doing is taking a base 10 number that's stored in the ax register and converting it to a binary string (e.g 10100b). The problem I'm having is that whenever ax is suppose to equal 1, it instead wraps over and equals some large number.

```
.code
main proc

   xor eax, eax
   xor ebx, ebx
   xor ecx, ecx
   xor edx, edx

   lea esi, binResult                           ; convert result to string (binary notation)
   mov ax, [result]
   mov bx, 2
   call Convert2Bin


   lea esi, binResult                           ; test
   call PrintString



   EndofProgram:

   invoke ExitProcess, 0            
main endp


Convert2Bin proc                       ; Define procedure
        pushad                     ; save registers
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        divide_Convert2Bin:

        cmp eax, 1
        je addOne_ThenExit

        cmp eax, 0
        je addZero_ThenExit

        div ebx

        cmp edx, 1
        je addOne_ThenLoop

        cmp edx, 0
        je addZero_ThenLoop

        addOne_ThenLoop:
        mov byte ptr [esi], '1'
        inc esi
        jmp divide_Convert2Bin

        addZero_ThenLoop:
        mov byte ptr [esi], '0'
        inc esi
        jmp divide_Convert2Bin

        addOne_ThenExit:
        mov byte ptr [esi], '1'
        inc esi
        jmp done_Convert2Bin

        addZero_ThenExit:
        mov byte ptr [esi], '0'
        inc esi
        jmp done_Convert2Bin

        done_Convert2Bin:
        mov byte ptr [esi], 'b'

        popfd                      ; restore flags
        popad                      ; restore registers
        ret                        ; return to caller
```

Comment: `pusha/popa` and` and `pushf/popf` are both fairly slow.  You *can* make up your own ABI on a per-function basis when writing in asm, but saving/restoring *everything* is a bad choice.  The standard ABIs don't preserve flags, and have some caller-saved registers that can use in functions without saving.  You only need to save/restore the registers that the ABI specifies as callee-saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div ebx` needs as input certain values in `EAX`, `EBX` and `EDX` and changes `EAX` and `EDX`. At least you've forgotten the initialization of `EDX`:

```
...
pushfd                     ; save flags

mov ebx, 2                 ; Divisor

divide_Convert2Bin:

cmp eax, 1
je addOne_ThenExit

cmp eax, 0
je addZero_ThenExit

xor edx, edx                ; Don't forget to initialize EDX
div ebx
...
```

Consider, that you get the result (the remainders) in **reverse** order!

Comment: @lasec0203: You must repeat the initialization of `EDX` every time before the `div`, since `div` changes `EDX`.

Comment: I checked EDX in the debugger. It gets overwritten with a new remainder everytime. It doesn't seem to be causing the problem with EAX wrapping over.

Comment: @lasec0203: WTF ;-) Do it like I did and look at the result!

Comment: @lasec0203: `div` computes `EDX:EAX` / `src` -> `EAX` (and remainder in `EDX`).  Check the instruction manual.  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: @rkhb alright, I initialized edx like you have done and now the roll over has stop. I'm still not sure how the remainder is effecting what's in in eax.

Comment: @lasec0203: You have a loop. The first loop computes EDX:EAX/BX -> EAX, remainder EDX. EDX is needed before `div` and changed after `div`. In the second loop `div` get a wrong `EDX`, EDX:EAX is now a quite big number. You only want to work with `EAX`, so you can nullify the wrong `EDX` (`xor edx,edx`). When you program assembly, you have always to check whether the registers still hold the right values.

Comment: I finally get it now. So EDX:EAX is like combining both registers to be divided by EBX. The textbook calls EDX:EAX the implicit operand.

Comment: My problem was not understanding what EDX:EAX was implying. It's clear now.